# Two Angular CLI apps on the same page

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I created a web part for SharePoint and in this web part I use a solution written in the Angular CLI. But it turned out that the page already has a web part with the Angular CLI. When updating a page, only one web part works, either the first or the second. Is it possible to make both web parts work?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yszn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGsgG.png)

Comment: Can you add the code snippet or screenshot of the view to understand better?

Comment: Added screen screenshots to the question.